# C# JSONConvert Changing float value?

Tags: c#, json, floating-point

Im consuming a Web API using JSON , where one of the properties of the object I am bringing back is of type FLOAT.

After inserting the data into the database I started noticing some strange results here and there. I have just stepped through the code and I can see that the value of the float property "PERSUNQ":124736684.0 .

However, the minute that I touch the JSON data using JSONConvert, the value magically changes to :124736688.0

```
 GRSAPIData = client.DownloadString(GRSURL);   <!--- value is correct

 Rootobject root = (Rootobject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(GRSAPIData); <-- value is magically changed
```

The two lines above are one after the other (no code in between) and I assue you ive checked everywhere and I am not changing the value myself.

Is there something I should be aware of when using JSONConvert when dealing with floats that can explain this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you upload your JSON and Rootobject class?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I doubt that the database is relevant here.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I cant really post up anything too detailed as this is for a government project but Ill see what I can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `float` only has 7 digits of precision - that leading to the problem you're seeing. You can see this without getting JSON involved at all:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float f = 124736684.0f;
        Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("r")); // Round-trip
    }
}
```

Output:

```
124736688
```

Basically, the closest representable `float` value to 124736684 is 124736688.

It looks like you should probably use `double` instead - or potentially `decimal`, depending on what the value is meant to represent.

Comment: :\ Christ that's annoying. The schema of the data from the supplier has that field as a float. I guess Ill have to try and convert this to a double.Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for your answer +1 to you.